# ImageMagick on Wamp

Tags: php, image, apache, imagemagick, wamp

I have a problem with `imagemagick` on `wamp`. I searched a lot but failed to find the solution. My problem is that when I try to check if it is loaded or not, it shows me this error:

```
Caught exception: UnableToOpenModuleFile 
C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.magick\IM_MOD_RL_png_.dll: 
No such file or directory @ warning/module.c/GetMagickModulePath/811
```

I used the following calling code:

```php
try {
  // Let's check whether we can perform the magick.
  if (TRUE !== extension_loaded('imagick')) {
    throw new Exception('Imagick extension is not loaded.');
  } 

  // This check is an alternative to the previous one.
  // Use the one that suits you better. 
  if (TRUE !== class_exists('Imagick')) {
    throw new Exception('Imagick class does not exist.');
  }
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo 'Caught exception: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

EDIT: Nobody?

Comment: Could you please add the calling code, so one can check it ?

Comment: I use this one:
try 
{ 
    // Let's check whether we can perform the magick. 
    if (TRUE !== extension_loaded('imagick')) 
    { 
        throw new Exception('Imagick extension is not loaded.'); 
    } 

    // This check is an alternative to the previous one. 
    // Use the one that suits you better. 
    if (TRUE !== class_exists('Imagick')) 
    { 
        throw new Exception('Imagick class does not exist.'); 
    }
} 

catch (Exception $e) 
{ 
    echo 'Caught exception: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n"; 
}

Comment: @ethernum have you found a solution yet?